# Drag and drop Beautiful dnd

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm building a web app with the drag and drop context but the issue is whenever the last element leaves one of the columns the particular column disappears

I used beautiful dnd, I tried using separate card components, I tried using different functions but all to no avail.. I want the column to remain even after removing the last draggable element out of it

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.